# How to get a depth point from screen space using Tango and Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

I want to find a point in world space at the center of the viewport using the point cloud from the Unity Tango integration. I'll then place a "reticle" type GameObject there.

I'm basing my code off the point_to_point example in the [C API examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c).

`TangoSupport_getDepthAtPointNearestNeighbor` is the function that will do what what I need, but it requires a pose parameter.

The C API says this is:

```
The pose of the point cloud relative to the color camera used to obtain uv_coordinates.
```

The Unity API says this is:

```
Transformation matrix of the color camera with respect to the Unity World frame.
```

The point_to_point example calls:

```
TangoSupport_calculateRelativePose(
  color_image_timestamp, TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR,
  point_cloud->timestamp, TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH,
  &pose_color_camera_T_depth_camera);
```

to find the pose.

But this doesn't exist in the Unity integration. I've tried adding it manually like this:

```
internal const string TANGO_SUPPORT_UNITY_DLL = "tango_support_api";
[DllImport(TANGO_SUPPORT_UNITY_DLL)]
private static extern int TangoSupport_calculateRelativePose(
    double base_timestamp, TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType base_frame,
    double target_timestamp, TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType target_frame,
    out TangoPoseData base_frame_T_target_frame);
```

And calling it like this:

```
TangoPoseData poseData = new TangoPosedata();

TangoSupport_calculateRelativePose(
    pointCloudData.m_timestamp,
    TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_COLOR,
    pointCloudData.m_timestamp,
    TangoEnums.TangoCoordinateFrameType.TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_CAMERA_DEPTH,
    out poseData
);
```

But this give me a null ref when I call it. Am I taking the right approach? Does `TangoSupport_calculateRelativePose` exist in the tango_support_api library that ships with the Unity integration?

There is a point_to_point example in the Unity package. But uses a C# function `FindClosestPoint`, which just iterates through every point in the point cloud, which not a usable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, `FindClosestPoint` is not available through Unity. The closest substitution is the FindPlane function in PointCloud prefab. See the function [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/blob/920dc9d4a145ae681681ab75789b0e645a626d9c/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoPrefabs/Scripts/TangoPointCloud.cs#L360).

Comment: Is the comment in the source accurate? "This function is slow, as it looks at every single point in the point cloud". It differs from the doc on [FitPlaneModelNearClick](https://developers.google.com/tango/apis/java/support/reference/TangoSupport.html#fitPlaneModelNearPoint-TangoPointCloudData-TangoPoseData-float-float-). `FindClosestPoint` explicitly loops through every point.

Comment: It is correct. The `FindClosestPoint` function in Unity does loop through all points. However, the FindPlane function in Unity calls into C Support Library's `FitPlaneModelNearClick` under the hood.

Comment: I meant that the `FitPlaneModelNearClick` function also has the same comment. I was wondering if it actually is slow as it calls `FitPlaneModelNearClick`, or whether that comment is a copy/paste error?

Comment: `FitPlaneModelNearClick` doesn't traverse through all points. But it might be slower than `FindCloestPoint`. It does a RANSAC plane fitting under the hood.